# Objective C UIViewController subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

Recently I've been looking into [RESideMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu). What really piqued my interest was his 'UIViewController+RESideMenu.h/m'. It appears to me that this is a way to subclass a UIViewController. It includes IBActions and methods in it that are accessible from anything that inherits from UIViewController.

All of my attempts to replicate this have failed. Is there a special way to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually that sort of classname is used to denote a category. Instead of subclassing it adds additional methods and properties to a class. For more information see here: [CustomizingExistingClasses](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

Comment: Would the equivalent of these be Extensions in Swift?

Comment: @Henry I'm not an expert on swift (haven't switched over yet), but based on basic research yes. Based on [this](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) page  _Extensions are similar to categories in Objective-C_

Comment: It's just that all of the preliminary research that I've done on extensions doesn't extend anything beyond basic types.

Comment: @Henry Again I'm not sure about swift, but it seems that they can extend any type (not sure what you mean by basic types).